# Nested Skips (UPenn)

Tags: javascript, performance, array

> **Exercise 1: skips :: [a] -> [[a]]**
>
> The nth list in the output should contain every nth element from the
>   input list. For example, skips "hello!" == ["hello!", "el!", "l!",
>   "l", "o", "!"].

The question [UPenn Homework 3: skips function](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/85095/upenn-homework-3-skips-function) and it's associated answers inspired me to write a solution in Javascript. I used the opportunity to (finally) better understand high order array functions. If you would be so kind to critique:

1. Code Layout, specifically if nesting `function skips()` makes any sense and why.
2. Do higher order functions provide more than just readability, are they more efficient?
3. Can I make the nested `function skips()` better (readable/faster)?
4. Anything at all.

```
function skip(str, cb) {
  var input = str.split('');

  cb(input.map(skips));

  function skips(val, index, arr) {
    var res = [];
    var i = index;
    var iterator = i + 1;
    for (i; i < arr.length; i += iterator){
      res.push(arr[i]);
    }
    return res;
  }
}

skip('hello!', console.log);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with most of what @Dair said, but disagree with polluting the global namespace with a `skipHelper()` that is of little value to anyone else.

I'd also make a few tweaks to the helper:

- It can be an anonymous function.
- I'd call the first parameter `_` to indicate that it is unused.
- `var i` can be declared in the `for` loop header.
- `extracted` would be a slightly more descriptive name than `res`.

```
function skips(str) {
    return str.split('').map(function(_, index, array) {
        var extracted = [];
        for (var i = index; i < array.length; i += 1 + index) {
            extracted.push(array[i]);
        }
        return extracted.join('');
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. A follow up questions on your answer. Is there a benefit of using an anonymous function?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, first off: Passing in `console.log` as a paramater seems unnecessary. The function should have one task:

> Generate the skips

Then once you have the skips you can do whatever you want with it. So:

```
function skip(str, cb) -> function skip(str)
```

and:

```
skip('hello!', console.log); -> console.log(skip('hello'));
```

I would also not use a function within a function. I would try keeping the functions relatively small. [Split the functions](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/195989/is-it-ok-to-split-long-functions-and-methods-into-smaller-ones-even-though-they):

```
function skipHelper(val, index, arr) {
  var res = [];
  var i = index;
  var iterator = i + 1;
  for (i; i < arr.length; i += iterator){
    res.push(arr[i]);
  }
  return res;
}

function skip(str) {
  var input = str.split('')
  return input.map(skips);
}
```

Also, given that `str.split('')` isn't too much to explicitly write out, change:

```
  var input = str.split('')
  return input.map(skips);
```

To just:

```
  return str.split('').map(skips);
```

Also, your code doesn't run exactly as described. Add a `.join('')` to `return res;` and this should fix it:

```
return res; -> return res.join('');
```

All in all:

```
function skipHelper(val, index, arr) {
  var res = [];
  var i = index;
  var iterator = i + 1;
  for (i; i < arr.length; i += iterator){
    res.push(arr[i]);
  }
  return res.join('');
}

function skip(str) {
  return str.split('').map(skipHelper);
}

console.log(skip('hello!'));
```

There are probably some Javascript language specific stylistic choices I am missing, but this is for general code structure.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for the response. Passing `console.log` is useless and it was used as a placeholder, your layout is much cleaner. I was attempting to model an async function.